# Creating an instance of a FireBreath plugin using ActiveXObject

Tags: firebreath, activexobject

I am using FireBreath to create a cross browser plugin. In the HTML test page i am using the following function to detect whether the plugin is installed and to initiate a download of the MSI installer if the plugin is not detected.

```
function checkPlugin(){
    var pluginInstalled = false;
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Win') != -1)) {
        // For IE 
        var pluginObject = null;
        try {
            pluginObject = new ActiveXObject('Test.TestPlugin');
            if(pluginObject){
                pluginInstalled = true;
                //pluginObject.Dispose();
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // Cannot load the plugin. Most probably it's not installed
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    }else{
        // For other browsers
        pluginInstalled = (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-test"] && navigator.plugins["TestPlugin"]);
    }
    return pluginInstalled; 
}
```

Above function works fine on all other browsers except for IE. It causes both IE 9 and 10 to crash when it attempts to create an instance of the plugin using ActiveXObject. I have noted that support for this functionality was added from FireBreath 1.4 onwards but I believe i am using the latest version of FireBreath which is 1.7. Any assistance in solving this issue is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the method used in the [FireBreath javascript detection example](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/Installer/js/fb_installer.js), and that's what I'm using in my plugins.  You weren't entirely clear on what version you're using; are you on 1.7? It works for me on 1.6 and 1.7 for sure.

If you could be a little more specific about where it crashes that might be easier to make some speculations; try attaching a debugger.  For information on how to force IE to be single process to make attaching a debugger see the "[Debugging Plugins](http://www.firebreath.org/x/MYAG)" page on firebreath.org.